# How to display Firebase Auth user profile image in SwiftUI?

Tags: firebase, facebook, firebase-authentication, gmail, swiftui

I do this, but give me this error --> `Cannot convert value of type 'URL' to expected argument type 'String'`

```swift
  var profilePic = URL(string: Auth.auth().currentUser?.photoURL as Any as! String) as Any as! URL

  var body : some View { 
    VStack {
      Image(self.profilePic)
    }
  }
```

How can I display the user's profile image?

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI's Image view is unable to load remote images from the network.  The standard practice would be to install [SDWebImageSwiftUI](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImageSwiftUI) using a dependency manager like [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/).  The following would then work effectively:

```
import SwiftUI
import SDWebImageSwiftUI
import FirebaseAuth

struct ProfilePicView: View {
     var body: some View {
         WebImage(url: Auth.auth().currentUser?.photoURL)
     }
}
```

You can then apply the same modifiers to WebImage as you would image, and it handles all of your networking for you.